# Is there a (relatively) clear consensus for Hange Zoe's gender?

Tags: attack-on-titan

A common conclusion by English speaking followers of SnK is that Hange Zoe is nonbinary, since there is no specific reference to Hange's gender in the language used in the manga. (See [here](http://www.dailydot.com/fandom/attack-titan-snk-hange-hanji-gender-debate/) for an example.) On the flip side, the in-text justification that gendered-pronouns aren't used isn't useful in the original Japanese context, and there are a bunch of other key characters to whom this lack of gender-specific reference applies to. (I'm also a cynic, and I have seen enough cases of cultural myopia among English speaking animanga fans that I'm simply a bit suspicious.)

In any case, there seems to be a great deal of drama floating around about this - for instance, some of the posts [here](http://calorescence.tumblr.com/tagged/hanji-zoe-gender-wank).

There's also been [the suggestion](http://papermoon2.tumblr.com/post/73722925844/i-think-this-confusion-about-non-binary-hange-is) that the creators don't care what gender Hange is assigned to, but since this indifference apparently (at least according to the OP) extends to all characters (even those who seem relatively well-defined as male or female), I'm sceptical of the value of this fact.

Is there anything clear consensus (or "restriction" that at least rules out some possibilities) with regards to Hange Zoe's gender, from a culturally aware interpretation of the material from SnK? [I'm asking this in part since it probably would be useful to have a "resource", and while I have my own vague conclusions based on webpages and blog posts like the above, I believe it'd be useful to get other perspectives, particularly as someone who has not followed the manga.]

Comment: jesus christ tumblr

Comment: @senshin: I don't spend much time at all on it beyond browsing a bit when stuff like this comes up, but the various fandoms there seem to be at times really not particularly worth my while with anything _vaguely_ related to Western social justice...

Answer (score 3):

In the Anime, Hange is clearly female. In the manga, it's left for the reader to interpret.

[Source](http://kodanshacomics.tumblr.com/post/79565073216/you-publish-attack-on-titan-right-a-friend) and [Source](http://shingekinokyojin.wikia.com/wiki/Hange_Zo%C3%AB)